# Long Run VAR alpha and beta significance levels

Tags: statistical-significance, estimation, vector-autoregression

I am using a VAR with 2 variables and 4 lags. I am combining the coefficients of these variables to get an overall alpha and beta value for in the form $Y = \alpha + \beta X$.
In order to get the long run alpha, I am using the following formula:

$\alpha = \frac C {1-\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3-\alpha_4}$, where the alphas are the coefficients for lagged $Y,\ C$ is the constant.[image].

and the following formula for the beta calculation:

$\beta = \frac{\beta_1+\beta_2+\beta_3+\beta_4}{1-\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\alpha_3-\alpha_4}$, where $\beta$s are coefficients for lagged $X$ and $\alpha$ are coefficients for lagged $Y$.

Am I correct in saying that these provide the LONG RUN alpha and beta values, or are these equations incorrect?
**Also, and most importantly, what equation would I use to find the    significance of these headline alpha and beta values? Are they    derived from the standard errors/t-stats?**

Attached is an example of the above, with the headline alpha and beta coefficients derived from the above formulas.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Nick,

I just wanted to thank you for updating my question to make it more legible - apologies but I couldn't work out how to private message you so thought i'd message you on here. I don't suppose you have any idea with regards to my question do you?